# Scroll inside a div using other div scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to be able to scroll (vertically) inside a div using another div's scrollbar but can't manage to get my head around this.

Tired using something like this, but I need to manually insert content into `DIV B` (which I don't want) in order for it's scrollbar to appear.

What's the proper way to do this?

My code:

```
    $('.DIV B').height = $('DIV A').height
    $('.DIV B').on('scroll', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $('DIV A').prop('scrollTop', this.scrollTop).prop('scrollLeft', this.scrollLeft)
    })
```

Check this image:

[image]

Comment: So you want to scroll a div which has no scrollbars?

Comment: @WaisKamal Yes, `DIV B` doen't have a scrollbar. The goal is to remove `DIV A` scrollbar` and use it in `DIV B` somehow.

Comment: Why would you want to scroll a div which is wide enough to hold its contents without the need for scrollbars? This is not even possible.

Comment: @WaisKamal The reason is a UI one, in my use case is considered to be easier for the user to understand if `DIV A` scrollbar is on the far right of the screen. (maybe `DIV B`). LE. I must scroll vertically (overflow-y), edited the post! Sorry for that

Comment: Get the `scrollTop` of DIV A and use `scrollTo(0,x)` on DIV B where x is the `scrollTop` of DIV A, but note that this will not work if DIV B is not scrollable.

Comment: it's a big fuss for not much, trust your user , they'll find out how to scroll that div . use a scrollbar from elsewhere then is confusing and tricky, it will look like a bug

Comment: @WaisKamal Do you have any tips for making `DIV B` scrollable, I had an idea for `DIV B` to be vertically scrollable by adding a `div` child inside him, and add several items in this `div child` (based probably on how many childs does `DIV A` has?), this will make my `DIV B` scrollable. Also (hide those `childs` using something like `visibility:hidden`)

Comment: Your idea should work. If this what you want, go ahead.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I agree, but I must make this work this way somehow.

Comment: @WaisKamal The next issue that happened after playing around with the DOM using my idea was that, using my code above I was able to scroll in both the sidebars (which is good) but what's not good is as I scroll in the `DIV B` those divs which where `visbility: hidden` appear (cause `visibility hidden` duh). Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: What makes them appear?

Comment: @WaisKamal Well, by appear I mean the following. I don't want to acually scroll the content's of `DIV B`, but instead use `DIV B` scrollbar to trigger scrolling into `DIV A`. I tried using `e.preventDefault` but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please post your attempts in the question. It is very difficult to tell what problem you are facing.

Comment: @WaisKamal You can check out what I meant in my last comment [here](https://jsbin.com/pasajetaqa/6/edit?html,js,console,output) (Check the left div, by moving his scrollbar I don't want to actually scroll into him, just only use his scrollbar to trigger the right div scrollbar)

Comment: the thing is that box a and B don't have the same height on your screenshot, you need somehow to  translate the proper scrolling ratio to the box to scroll. here is an example similar to your description needs https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/ZEpOBPj , then you need to update the thing onresize too ... I'm curious of that UI you say this behavior is required , to know about it might help to understand your goal.

Comment: AFAIK you can't move the scrollbar while keeping the contents in place. You should either create a custom scrollbar or use a fixed position div and make it hold the contents you want to remain in place while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I made up a funny demo here. Which is quite theorical. I mean I think it does reflect what you wish to do (from my understanding), but may not work just like this on first shot in your real layout and content...

So in the below snippet *(run in full screen please)*, I reproduced a layout "looking like" the image you provided. And if you click on the "Move the scrollbar" button, it is what you want *(again, from my understanding)*.

So... The idea here is to demonstrate how you could "hide" the `A` div scrollbar with CSS. See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-scrollbars) for more. And then create a div to hold only a scrollbar which would be "linked to the `A` div" and which you could position where you wish it to be.

So take it as a possible boost in your custom UI exploration ;)

```js
let bigContent = "";
for (i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
  bigContent += "A<br>";
}
bigContent += "END<br>";

$("#A").html(bigContent);

$("#move").click(function () {
  $("#A").toggleClass("noScrollBar");
  $("#Z")
    .html($("#A").html())
    .css("height", $("#A").height() + "px")
    .toggle();
});

$("#Z").on("scroll", function () {
  $("#A").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#A {
  border: 3px solid pink;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#B {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}
#C {
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 60%;
}
#D {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  height: 6em;
}
#E {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
}
.noScrollBar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}
#Z {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 1em 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="E">
    <div id="C">
      <div id="A">
        A
      </div>
      <div id="D">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="B">B
      <div id="Z"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="move">Move the scrollbar</button>
</body>
```

I made it up in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zYKBNmG?editors=1111)... If you want to play with it. Feel free to fork. ;)

Comment: @johnDoe no comments on this answer?